# How can i merge several dictionaries by a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

This is my code:

```py
a = int(input())

for i in range(a):
    b = input()
    
    b = b.split(".")#creating a list

    #print(b)
    
    b[1]= b[1].lower()
    b[1]=b[1].capitalize()
    a=b[1]
    #print(b[1])
    
    #print(b[0] , b [1] , b[2])

    dic = {}
    dic_final={}
    dic={b[1] : {'name':b[0] ,'lan':b[2] }}
    dic_final.update(dic)
    del(dic)


print(dic_final)
```

My input :

```
2 
f.sara.python
m.john.java
```

Output has to be like :

```
{ 'sara':{'gender':'f' , 'lan':'python'} , 'john':{'gender':'m' , 'lan':'python'}}
```

But i always get the last dictionary item i wrote in the input :

```
{'john':{'gender':'m' , 'lan':'python'}
```

How can i solve it and get a dictionary like below?

```
{ 'sara':{'gender':'f' , 'lan':'python'} , 'john':{'gender':'m' , 'lan':'python'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a very clear solution that i came up with

```
    num_sample = int(input("how many test cases?: "))
    final = {}
    for case in range(num_sample):
        new_case = input("insert new case: ")
        gender, name, lan = new_case.split(".")
        info = {"gender": gender, "lan": lan}
        final[name] = info

    #access final from here
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the dic_final dictionary in the for loop each time.
This line is causing the issue `dic_final={}`

Solution:
Add this line before your 'for loop' and remove the declaration inside.
`dic_final = dict()`

Better coding style:

```
a = int(input())

dic_final = dict()

for i in range(a):
    b = input()
    
    gender, name, lan = b.split(".")

    name = name.capitalize()
    dic_final.update({name : {"gender": gender, "lan": lan}})

print(dic_final)
```

Output:

```
2
f.sara.python
m.john.java
{'Sara': {'gender': 'f', 'lan': 'python'}, 'John': {'gender': 'm', 'lan': 'java'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a global dictionary instead of creating a local one in the for loop. Moreover in your code, you are naming `gender` as `name`

```
a = int(input())

dic_final = {}

for i in range(a):
    b = input()
    
    b = b.split(".")
    
    b[1]= b[1].lower()
    b[1]=b[1].capitalize()
    a=b[1]

    dic={b[1] : {'gender':b[0] ,'lan':b[2] }}
    dic_final.update(dic)
    del(dic)


print(dic_final)
```

Output:

```
2
f.sara.python
m.john.java
{'Sara': {'gender': 'f', 'lan': 'python'}, 'John': {'gender': 'm', 'lan': 'java'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting only the last entry is because , you are re-initialising the dictionary for every iteration.

All you have to do is , make "dic_final" global .